# codeigniter3, find total number of hits based on time data

Tags: mysql, group-by, codeigniter-3

I have a table where I record instants of request between user `requestFrom` to user `requestTo` against `requestTime`. It looks like as follows.

| id | requestFrom | requestTo | requestTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | bbb | 10001 |
| 2 | aaa | bbb | 10002 |
| 3 | aaa | ccc | 10003 |
| 4 | eee | ccc | 10004 |
| 5 | eee | ccc | 20000 |
| 6 | eee | ccc | 20001 |

I need to group the result based on, if requests are occurred within delta(say 2 seconds) time and also if request happened between same `requestFrom` `and` `requestTo`, it should be considered as one instant in the result.  Based on that the output looks like

| time | number of hits | remark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10002 | 1 | id 1 and 2 combined |
| 10003 | 1 | id 3 |
| 10004 | 1 | here id 5 and 6 did not combine with id 4, because delta is > 2 |
| 20001 | 1 | id 5 and 6 combined |

here I can use `group_by(requestFrom, requestTo)`, but how do I incorporate `requestTime` delta.

how can I write a codeigniter Model function inorder to achieve above result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain the mathematics that is to be implemented. If that's understood, then you should have no problem implementing this for your table.

Now, you already have two aggregations. This means that your records are grouped by `requestFrom` and the records grouped by `requestFrom` are grouped further by `requestTo`. Now, you have to `group by` a third criteria. In order to define such a criteria, you need to formulate it in your own words first, in such a way that it can be transformed into formulas that can be tested easily:

1. We identify the first type of left-hand-side of such intervals in such a way that there does not exist another element that's earlier by less than delta.
2. We identify the members of such intervals in such a way that we can find a left-hand-side that's not older than the given element by more than delta.

This can be achieved by a join.

However, it's possible that a request from a to b was sent in such a way that it's newer than the left-hand-side by more than delta, but less new from the right-hand-side than delta. So, once you get this result, you can run a similar query, which differs only in the fact that it would search for items that fit this edge-case and group them similarly. You can run this second query, extending the filters each time by the groups and intervals already found, until there are no new groups.

This is a solution that should definitely work, but it's consisting of multiple queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  what I understood is, it takes multiple  queries. I have implemented  different solution, where, I retrieve all the data from database. Then wrote a code in controller with  `foreach` loop and `if` `else` condition to sort the data.

Comment: @sadath that's also possible, yes. Basically you either execute multiple queries in a script, that is, your RDBMS would do most of the work with less network load, or, you could load all the raw stuff into memory via the RDBMS, send it to the application server's memory, which, in turn would parse it. Either way is possible.

Comment: I had a different understanding about the network load and memory load. I thought, loading raw data to memory (and doing processing) is better than multiple queries.  For current requirement i am loading very less raw data in to memory . I should try both, as a beginner. How can I calculate and compare total processing time? I really  appreciate your time.

Comment: @sadath if you send different queries to the RDBMS, then that will load a lot of memory on both sides and the network. Yet, if you write a stored procedure/function and do all the stuff internally, rendering the application only the job of calling that stored procedure and receiving the values it returns, then you can save a lot of memory. But ultimately in order to determine what the best solution is you need to quantify the problem. With small amount of data whatever the result is, it will not be very reliable.

Comment: In order to properly test it, you need to ensure that there is a lot of data to be processed and plenty of examples of all scenarios (possibly by generating some data into your database). Measuring the needed time is certainly possible, see https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html